# Accessing Global Temporary Table through pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, temp-tables, azure-data-studio

I am operating a python 3 notebook in Azure Data Studio (similar to jupyter notebook) and trying to access an existing global temp table (##TEMP1) via pyodbc.

Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect(
    Trusted_Connection="yes",
    driver="{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}",
    host="SERVERNAME",
    database=db,
    trustServerCertificate="yes",
    multisubnetfailover="yes",
    applicationIntent="ReadOnly",
)

sql = """
select * from ##TEMP1
"""

data = pd.read_sql(sql, con)

con.close()
data.head()
```

In Azure Data Studio, when I switch the kernel to sql and simply query select * from ##TEMP1, it returns results, however when I try to run via the python code above via pyodbc, it's returning the following error.

> DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql ' select * from ##TEMP1 ':
>   ('####', "[####] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Invalid object name '##TEMP1'. (###) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Please help, those much smarter than I! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

I use pyodbc to make the connection and query the database. As you can see I create a curser with pyodbc and execute the curser with the SQL query string as an argument. Then use `fetchall()` to return the result for the curser

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_Connection='yes', driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',host = 'SERVERNAME', database = db,trustServerCertificate='yes',multisubnetfailover='yes',applicationIntent='ReadOnly')

crsr = conn.cursor()

sql = '''
select * from ##TEMP1
'''

crsr.execute(sql)

results = crsr.fetchall()

con.close()
data.head()
```